# how to select check in and check out using webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape the "Booking.com" website but i can't get the price since i can't force the code below to chose a date in the date field , i used the same method that i use to send the town field to send the date field .
I managed this code as below :

```
import re
import time
import csv

from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

CITIES=["Bordeaux,france"]
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
for city in CITIES:
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ss").send_keys(city)  # Enter City Name
    # Wait until autosuggestion come and click on first suggestion
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]')))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frm"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul[1]/li[1]').click()

    check_in_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    check_out_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(time.time()) + 604800).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    # Waits for Datetime widget and select check In date
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div')))
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frm"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]').click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div')))
    table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="frm"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/'
                                          'div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table//td')
    for x in table:
        if x.get_attribute("data-id") and datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x.get_attribute("data-id")[:-3])).strftime(
                "%Y-%m-%d") == check_in_time:
            x.click()

    # Waits for Datetime widget and select check Out date
    ### A voir 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frm"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]').click()

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="frm"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div')))
    table = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="frm"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/'
                                          'div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table//td')
    for x in table:
        if x.get_attribute("data-id") and datetime.fromtimestamp(int(x.get_attribute("data-id")[:-3])).strftime(
                "%Y-%m-%d") == check_out_time:
            x.click()

    # Click Search Button
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('sb-searchbox__button').click()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.get("https://www.booking.com/")

# Enter City Name
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ss").send_keys(city)

# Wait until autosuggestion come and click on first suggestion
condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located(
   (By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#ss + ul > li:nth-child(1)'))

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(condition).click()

check_in_date = datetime
    .fromtimestamp(int(time.time())).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
check_out_date = datetime
    .fromtimestamp(int(time.time()) + 604800).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# choose check in date
select_date(check_in_date)

# choose check out date
select_date(check_out_date, False)
```

Function `select_date`:

```
def select_date(date_to_select, isCheckInDate=True):
    data_mode = "checkin" if isCheckInDate else "checkout"

    # Wait datepicker visible
    try:
        locator = 'div[data-mode="{0}"] + div'.format(data_mode)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, locator)))

    except TimeoutException:
        # click the `+` button to display the datepicker
        locator = 'div[data-mode="{0}"] button.sb-date-field__icon-btn'.format(data_mode)

        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(locator).click()

    dateFound = False

    # iterate 12 months
    for i in rang(0, 12):

        # the datepicker which will display two month per time
        # find the first visible month in datepicker

        locator = 'div[data-mode="{0}"] + div div.c2-calendar-inner'.format(data_mode)
        style = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(locator).get_attribute('style')

        margin_left = re.search(r'(\d+)', style).group(1)

        # find all days in first visible month indatepicker
        locator = 'div[data-mode="{0}"] + div div[data-offset="{1}"]' +
                  ' td[data-id]:not(.c2-day-s-disabled)'.format(data_mode, margin_left)

        days = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(locator)

        for day in days:
            data_id = day.get_attribute("data-id")
            date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(data_id[:-3])).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            print 'iterate date: ' + date

            if date == date_to_select:
                day.click()
                dateFound = True
                return

        # if not found in first visible month,
        # click the right arrow to scroll month 
        locator = 'div[data-mode="{0}"] + div  div.c2-button-further'.format(data_mode)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(locator).click()

    if dateFound == False:
        print 'Not found {0} date: {1}'.format(data_mode, date_to_select)
```

Comment: thanks, but i get an error in this line data-mode = isCheckInDate? "checkin":"checkout"

Comment: Updated that code line and change variable name `data-mode` to `data_mode`, former is illegal variable name.

Comment: yeah it's works now and i choose this date select_date("2018-05-18") for checkin but i get Not found checkin date: 2018-05-18

Comment: Did you get output like  `iterate date: 2018-05-18`?  I think you can debug the code.

Comment: No i get  'Not found checkin date: 2018-05-18 '

Comment: I have `print 'iterate date: ' + date` in the loop `for day in days:`,  So you never get any output like `iterate date: xxxx`?   If  yes, means the code not run into that loop.

Comment: that's what I did but it does not work either,  
can you show me your global code that works ?